override all method from model.php
Using Laravel V10.42.0
This is my route function
Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return view('posts',[
        'posts' => Post::All()
    ]);
});

This is my Posts.php file
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

}

This is the output.
App\Models\Post {#1268 ▼ // resources\views/posts.blade.php
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

it displaying me all posts like dd() method cuz of All Function from Model.php file how can i override it or solve this problem?
i tried to override all method from Model.php file but it didn't work for me

The problem from your view file that called posts please share it to help you

Share the entire code of Post.php model and it's migration file.

I already solved the problem.
I didn't notice that I'm was using dd() in the post view.
Thx for ur help sir.
